# How to get the partition with the least number of subsets that respects other partitions?

Tags: algorithm, set, partitioning

I have a set of elements and some arbitrary partitions of it.

I want to get a partition that divides the set in the least amount of subsets and "respects" the previous existing partitions. By respecting, I mean:

> Let A and B be partitions of set X. Partition A respects B if, for every two elements of X, e and f, if e and f are not in the same subset of X according to partition B, they are also not in the same subset of X according to partition A.

Example:

Set is `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

Partition1 is `{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}`

Partition2 is `{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}`

A partition that would respect Partition1 and Partition2 (and any other partition) is the "every element in its subset" `{{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}}` partition. However, I want the partition with the least number of subsets, in this case `{{1,2}, {3},{4}, {5,6}}`.

Is there an algorithm for this problem? I have googled quite a bit, but couldn’t find anything, probably because I am not being able to describe it well. However, it sounds like a generic problem that should be common.

(another way to describe the problem from this Wikipedia article would be: “how to get the coarsest partition that is finer than a set of arbitrary partitions”)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Comment: Roughly how large can the number of elements and the number of partitions be? Is it safe to assume the partitions are not typically of adjacent numbers?

Comment: @Dave almost 8 thousand elements. About 10 partitions with about 100 subsets in each. Yeah, there is no way to order the elements in a wat that elements that are usually in the same subset are adjacent.

I understand that due to my data pool an algorithm may not be viable, but I would still like to know the best solution so far.

Comment: Running my algorithm 100 times for 8000 elements, 10 partitions, and 100 subsets per partition (with random allocation of elements to partitions), I don't get a single instance where the respectful partition isn't entirely comprised of 1-element sets. My earlier analysis had an error.

Comment: Yea, you just need to take the intersection of all subsets containing the same elements, and repeat for each element not covered, which is Dave's answer.

Comment: @Dave A back of the envelope is that there are `31,996,000` distinct pairs, and the odds of any one of them winding up in the same partition is `10^(-20)` for odds of around `3.2e-13` of anything other than 1-element sets.  There is no surprise that you didn't hit any examples in 100 tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working Python:

```
def partition_to_lookup(partition):
    which_partition = {}
    i = 0
    for part in partition:
        for x in part:
            which_partition[x] = i
        i += 1
    return which_partition

def combine_partitions (partitions):
    lookups = [partition_to_lookup(partition) for partition in partitions]
    reverse_lookup = {}
    for x in lookups[0].keys():
        key = tuple((lookup[x] for lookup in lookups))
        if key in reverse_lookup:
            reverse_lookup[key].add(x)
        else:
            reverse_lookup[key] = {x}

    return list(reverse_lookup.values())

print(combine_partitions([[{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}], [{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}]]))
```

If `N` is the size of the universe, `m` is the number of partitions, and `k` the total number of all sets in all partitions, then this will be `O(N*m + k)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll call the partition we're looking for the answer.

We'll build the answer as follows:

1. Take any element not in the answer.
2. Take the intersection of the subset containing this element from each partition.
3. Add this subset to the answer.
4. Repeat.

We'll have to go through these steps once per subset in the answer. At the end, every element will be in a unique subset in the answer, and these will be as coarse as possible.

---

If the allocation of elements to partitions is random, it is extremely unlikely that any respectful partition has any subsets with more than one element, given 8000 elements, 10 partitions, and 100 subsets per partitions.

What are the odds of a particular pair of elements, say 1 & 2, being in the subset in all 10 partitions? Well, in each partition the odds are about 1/100, and there are 10 of these, so 1 in 100 ^ 10 = 1 in 10 ^ 20.

But there are only choose(8000,2) pairs, which is just under 3.2 * 10 ^ 7.

TL;DR: Unless your partitions aren't random and something about their construction puts the same elements together in subsets far more often than pure chance, the respectful set is almost certain to be 8000 single-element subsets.

---

Here's the code I used. It's Ruby. The first method generates random partitions, and the second implements the algorithm above.

```
def get_partitions(num_elts, num_partitions, num_subsets_per_partition)
  elements = 0.upto(num_elts - 1).to_a
  partitions = []
  num_partitions.times do
    elements.shuffle!
    partition = []
    splits = Set.new([0, num_elts])
    while splits.size < num_subsets_per_partition + 1 do
      splits.add(rand(num_elts))
    end
    splits_arr = splits.to_a.sort
    0.upto(splits_arr.size - 2) do |i|
      cur_split = splits_arr[i]
      next_split = splits_arr[i+1]
      cur_set = (elements.slice(cur_split, next_split - cur_split)).to_set
      partition.append(cur_set)
    end
    partitions.append(partition)
  end
  return partitions
end

def find_respectful_partition(num_elts, partitions)
  elements_set = 0.upto(num_elts - 1).to_set
  elt_to_subsets = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  partitions.each do |partition|
    partition.each do |subset|
      subset.each do |elt|
        elt_to_subsets[elt].append(subset)
      end
    end
  end
  answer = []
  while elements_set.size > 0 do
    elt = elements_set.first
    subsets_with_elt = elt_to_subsets[elt]
    respectful_subset = subsets_with_elt[0]
    subsets_with_elt.each do |subset_with_elt|
      respectful_subset = respectful_subset.intersection(subset_with_elt)
      break if respectful_subset.size == 1
    end
    answer.append(respectful_subset)
    elements_set.subtract(respectful_subset)
  end
  return answer
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I was trying to implement that first 4 steps algorithm that you posted but then btilly posted a Python code and I thought it would be easier to try that one.

Also thanks a lot for the statistical work, but I think I may have misled you. The "partitions'' are actually different ways to divide a geographic location. So it's hard to make them adjacent in an array, but yeah, they are not completely random or arbitrary as I may have made you believe. Indeed, using the btilly algorithm I got close to 500 subsets in the found partition.